# Cannot create subclass of SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, subclassing

Trying to subclass SKSpriteNode so make my game code cleaner, and I'm obviously not understanding something. Here's a very simple example: I create a new Swift file called `Alien.swift` with the following contents:

```
import SpriteKit

class Alien: SKSpriteNode {

}
```

In my game, I do:

```
    let alienSprite: Alien = Alien()
    print("It's an \(alienSprite)")
```

and I get:

> It's an (SKSpriteNode) name:'(null)...'

Even Xcode says it's an 'aliensSprite':

[image]

Why, at run-time, is it not printing that it's an 'alienSprite'?

Edit: incorporating one of my comments here - I'm actually picking up the sprite from my .sks file, where I placed it with the scene editor and set its custom class. I try to pick it up with:

```
let alien = childNodeWithName("alien") as! alienSprite
```

but I get the error:

```
Cannot cast SKSpriteNode to alientSprite
```

Comment: This is so basic - I've gotta be doing something stupid. I've checked tutorials I've followed and it looks the same. I don't think I need to override any initialisers at this stage, just to get a basic subclass.

Comment: That just seems to be the standard description method of SKSpriteNode, I don't let it confuse you. You can check the class at runtime with `print(type(of: alienSprite))` (Swift 3) or `print(alienSprite.dynamictype)` (Swift 2).

Comment: @MartinR Thanks - I'll do some more testing. I was originally picking up the Sprite from an .sks file (via childNodeWithName) and it was generating an exception that the cast from SKSpriteNode to Alien was failing.

Comment: @MartinR. Thanks for the tip about displaying the class, although the Swift2 version didn't work (no such property dynamicType).

Comment: OK that's annoying - it's now working and I don't know what I did. The 'Custom Class' field of my node in the scene editor seemed to blank every time I checked it (instead of 'PlayerShip', so perhaps it was an Xcode bug. I didn't need any initialisers either.

Comment: There is a typo in my last comment, its `print(alienSprite.dynamicType)` for Swift 2. – Voting to close as a problem that can no longer be reproduced.

Comment: Steve, hit cmd + s after you place in the sprite custom class (be sure to hit enter to get out of text edit mode)

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Thanks - I'll bear that in mind in future.

Comment: @MartinR it is possible to be reproduced, as seen in my answer

Comment: @Knight0fDragon - can you make your comment about how the scene editor doesn't always keep your custom class setting and answer and I'll upvote/accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveIves ok, I will try to provide pictures as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take notice to the state of your scene file.  If you see it shaded, this means it has not saved yet.  If you compile your code while still in the scene editor,  the save will not happen, so be sure to hit cmd + s to save prior to compiling.
[image]

Now in case people are trying to figure out why class names are not saving, make sure you hit ENTER or leave the text field and go to another textfield to ensure that the class name saves, otherwise it will revert back to an older state.

[image]

Comment: This fixed it - the scene editor seemed reluctant to retain the value I had put in for the custom class.

Answer (score 2):

**You are not using the name of the variable**

When you declare

```
 let alienSprite: Alien = Alien()
```

You are basically creating an empty SKSpriteNode. This means when you do the string interpolation, you are printing *the actual SKSpriteNode and its properties.*

To fix this, you have two options.

**Original**

1. Print the type of alienSprite:

   ```
   print("It's an \(type(of: alienSprite))")
   ```
2. Set the name of the Alien and print that:

   ```
   alienSprite.name = "Alien"
   print("It's an \(alienSprite.name)")
   ```

**10/25/16**

If you want something like @Knight0fDragon, you can do the following:

```
print("It's an \(type(of: alienSprite)) \(alienSprite)")
```

Which is basically an add on the my original answer.

Comment: No, this is creating an empty 'Alien', and I wanted to print the instance and it's properties because I thought that also printed the type of the instance, but it appears not. The 'name' property is completely different and unrelated to the class. I can't get your type() to work.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't know one backslash gets deleted on StackExchange. Try it now

Comment: He is saying that it is printing `It's an (SKSpriteNode) name:'(null)...'` instead of `It's an (Alien) name:'(null)...'`

Answer (score 1):

When you *print* an object, as in `print("It's an \(alienSprite)")`, you just ask to see its `description` property. By default for an `SKNode` this property just prints the `name` property of the object, as you didn't redefined this behavior you get the message `(SKSpriteNode) name: null`. If you want to redefine it then change the description in your new class to something more convenient, something like this should work:

```
class Alien : SKSpriteNode {
    override var description: String {
        return "\(String(describing: type(of:self)))"
    }
}
```

Remind that you also have a similar `debugDescription` to control what is printed by the debugger.

Comment: Is this Swift 3 only?

Comment: What is Swift 3 only is `type(of:)`, for older version you can use (can exactly remember but it is easy to find) something like `self.dynamicType`. `description` and `debugDescription` are standard mechanisms.